# Reference field from class not generating a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a GridView like this

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
            ID="gvDatos" runat="server" DataKeyNames="IdIngrediente"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4"
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged" onrowcreated="gvDatos_RowCreated" onpageindexchanging="gvDatos_PageIndexChanging">
```

This is the code that binds the data

```
List<Ingrediente> listaIngredientes = GestorABMCIngredientes.BuscarPorNombre(txtIngBuscar.Text);
gvDatos.DataSource = listaIngredientes;
string[] claves = { "IdIngrediente"};
gvDatos.DataKeyNames = claves;
gvDatos.DataBind();
```

And my class Ingrediente

```
public class Ingrediente
{
    public int IdIngrediente { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public UnidadMedida unidadMedida { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public double costoUnitario { get; set; }
    public bool requiereFrio { get; set; }
}
```

All fields of Ingrediente are generating columns properly, except for unidadMedida, the one that's not of type int, string, double, bool, etc.

I'd like to get a column for that field too, with the object's ToString() method (or any property of the class UnidadMedida, I'll manage).

I've thought of creating a new class `IngredienteForGridView` which has a string field instead of the type UnidadMedida, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

A screenshot of how my GridView is displaying. Please note that I've changed the columns' header text, and I've hidden columnd Id (it is the ONLY column I'm hiding, and this problem existed even before I implemented column hiding)[image]
Column unidadMedida is missing (from the row.cells count I deduce it's not being generated)

Comment: Is your columns auto generated?

Comment: Yes, they are autogenerated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a template field for this column in the markup?

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <TemplateField HeaderText="Blah">
            <%# ((UnidadMedida)Eval("unidadMedida")).YourMethodHere() %>
        </TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Worth noting that with this approach, some columns being auto generated and some columns customarily defined, you won't be able to control the order in which they appear. Custom columns will always come first.

If this is not the order you want, then your best bet is to list all columns you have in a custom way. Yes, a bit more work, but then you can get rid of hiding hacks, and you will also have more control over the grid view appearance. Luckily, there is no need to define templates for most of them:

```
<Columns>
    <BoudField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" />
    <TemplateField HeaderText="Blah">
        <%# ((UnidadMedida)Eval("unidadMedida")).YourMethodHere() %>
    </TemplateField>
    <BoudField DataField="costoUnitario" HeaderText="Costo Unitario"/>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Is there a way to do this in the code behind? Not that I strictly need it there, but since we're learning new stuff... :). I'll implement this in a minute and see how it goes

Comment: @Blueriver, to do what? Define custom columns? Yes, it can be done in code behind, but that's a very, very bad practice, because it will take much more code and much more maintenance then declaration in aspx. I strongly advice not to do it

Comment: I finally got some time to give this a try (lots of stuff happening...), and could get it to work. Thank you very much! I'll edit your answer a bit if you don't mind, slight changes for it to compile. Thank you again <3